# Samba same shared folder read only for guest and read write for @somegroup how to

Tags: permissions, samba, centos-6

I want users in group Audio to have read/write and all of the other
users (guest, anonymous, everyone....) to be able to browse and read
only access to the same share folder. Guest users cannot mount the shared point in windows. Audio group is fine. Can you please correct what is wrong with my smb.conf?

> ```
>  [global]
>  writeable = yes
>  path = /mnt/DANAS1/Audio
>  default = Audio
>  write list = @Audio
>  workgroup = WORKGROUP
>  os level = 20
>  comment = CBN Audio NAS1
>  map to guest = bad user
>  valid users = audio,eng,vj,@Audio
>  create mode = 765
>  security = user
>  directory mode = 765
>
> [AudioNAS]
>  comment = VBDAWAudio
>  path = /mnt/DANAS1/Audio 
>  available = yes 
>  browsable = yes 
>  public = yes 
>  writable = yes 
>  guest ok = yes
>  read only = guest
>  nobody printable = no
>  locking = no strict
>  locking = no
>  share modes = yes
>  create mask = 0755
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A mechanism you could use is manage the permissions on the actual files/folders. So you have have a single share of something like:

```
 [global]
 writeable = yes
 path = /mnt/DANAS1/Audio
 default = Audio
 write list = @Audio
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 os level = 20
 comment = CBN Audio NAS1
 map to guest = bad user
 valid users = audio,eng,vj,@Audio
 Guest ok = yest
 create mode = 764
 security = user
 directory mode = 764
```

Obviously the above will need your own flavor putting in since I don't know your plan for the rest of the share. With the files/folders in your share you set the group owner to audio (or whatever they are called) and set all permissions using chmod 764 (or something similar). This will allow:

File owner - Read, Write and Execute
Group - Read and Write
Other - Read

Don't think there is any reason why this sort of method wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks Matthew... I see you added Guest ok = yes and changed modes to 764 in [global] section. (btw I read somewhere it needs 765 because execute permission is needed for the user to go up/down the path)
That did not work. The thing is I want to apply these permissions (read only for guest and r/w for Audio group) to the shared directory with ALL OF THE SUBDIRECTORIES. As of now the whole shared tree is chowned to audio:Audio (and i feel there may be a problem). SElinux is disabled.